# Appending works without >> when redirecting standard output and error

Tags: bash, debian, io-redirection, ls

I have a file `test.txt` and have no file named `test`. When I tried

```
ls test test.txt > new 2>new
```

I was expecting `new` to be overwritten since `>>` is not used. But in the output file I got both contents appended. Why is it so?

Comment: To send both output AND stderr to a file: `command .... >file 2>&1` (in that order, which means: "1[stdout] now points to 'file'", AND THEN "2[stderr] now points to wherever 1 is pointing now" (ie, the file))

Comment: @OlivierDulac But in this case, there is no `2>&1` involved.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: that is precisely the point of my comment ^^ the OP seems to **want** to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same file [ie, I am not addressing the question, hence the comment, but I comment on the exposed command line which seems to want to do this but doesn't use the proper way to do it]

Comment: `> new 2> new` creates 2 _open file descriptions_ for each fd (which means stdout output will overwrite stderr (stderr is often first because unbuffered)), which `> new 2>&1` will create 1 _open file description_ shared by both fds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** `bash` opens and truncates all involved files before anything is written to them. `stdout` and `stderr` are both sent to `new` because `bash` has already truncated the file (twice) when `ls` starts printing.

This is how `bash` prepares/handles I/O redirection. When you ask for a command to be redirected (`>`) to a file, `bash` basically opens that file, creating it if necessary. If the file already exists, it is truncated. This is done through the `open` system call and a few flags, in your case:

```
open("new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)
```

`O_CREAT` creates the file if it does not exist, while `O_TRUNC` truncates it when it does. This `open` system call is part of `bash`'s initialisation for redirection, meaning that when you use several redirection operations, such as in...

```
$ ls test test.txt > new 2>new
```

... `bash` begins by opening all concerned files. Therefore, before running `ls`, it opens `new` twice, with the same flags:

```
open("new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)
open("new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)
```

This means that basically, when running your command, `bash` does the following (in that order) :

1. Open `new` as standard output, create/truncate the file when necessary.
2. Open `new` as standard error, create/truncate the file when necessary.
3. Run `ls`: this will write contents to `new`.

As you can see, `bash` truncates all involved files **before** starting `ls`. This means that when running something with `... >new 2>new`, `new` is basically truncated "twice", and **then**, outputs are redirected to it. The behaviour you are expecting would require `bash` to capture `ls`'s stdout and stderr independently, and to open them one after the other, just before writing. Basically:

1. Start `ls`.
2. When something comes on `stdout`, open `new`, truncate it and write to it.
3. When something comes on `stderr`, open `new` again, truncate it, and write to it.

However, messages may come out interweaven: the redirected program might very well write something to `stdout`, then something else to `stderr`, and then back on `stdout`... It would be horrible to manage all of that *(and it might lead to undesirable (undefined?) behaviours...)*.

Comment: `When something comes on stdout, open new, truncate it and write to it.` => This's completely wrong. All redirection was set up before `ls` running. When something comes on stdout, it just... comes on `new`, `new` had opened before, no need to open it again.

Comment: @cuonglm You may have read a little too quickly :x This is what *would* be necessary to implement the behaviour expected by the OP. I also mentionned how ridiculously useless and tricky this would be in practice. However, I described the actual behaviour at the beginning of my answer :)

Comment: "when running something with `... >new 2>new`, `new` is basically truncated "twice", and then, outputs are redirected to it." Yes, but an other important point missing here, as Stéphane Chazelas commented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180660/appending-works-without-when-redirecting-standard-output-and-error#comment300620_180660) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180660/appending-works-without-when-redirecting-standard-output-and-error#comment300636_180671), is that stderr will write to `new` first and then stdout will overwrite on it without truncating it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get both contents appended. You will get a weird output:

```
$ ls testasdasd qtsingleapp-homecu-bcbf-3e8 >new 2>new
$ cat new
qtsingleapp-homecu-bcbf-3e8
: No such file or directory
```

If you have both contents, you should see:

```
$ ls testasdasd qtsingleapp-homecu-bcbf-3e8 >new 2>&1
$ cat new
ls: cannot access testasdasd: No such file or directory
qtsingleapp-homecu-bcbf-3e8
```

So let do a `strace` to see what happened:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=open,close,write,fcntl,dup2 sh -c 'ls testasdsad qtsingleapp-homecu-bcbf-3e8 > new 2>new'
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
close(1)                                = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
open("new", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11
close(2)                                = 0
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 2)                              = 2
close(3)                                = 0
Process 7523 attached
....
[pid  7523] write(2, "ls: ", 4)         = 4
[pid  7523] write(2, "cannot access testasdsad", 24) = 24
[pid  7523] open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  7523] open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  7523] write(2, ": No such file or directory", 27) = 27
[pid  7523] write(2, "\n", 1)           = 1
[pid  7523] write(1, "qtsingleapp-homecu-bcbf-3e8\n", 28) = 28
[pid  7523] close(1)                    = 0
[pid  7523] close(2)                    = 0
Process 7523 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1
close(10)                               = 0
dup2(11, 2)                             = 2
close(11)                               = 0
```

Look at the sequences of `open`, `fcntl`, `dup2` you can see:

- First, file `new` is open, and assigned to file descriptor `3`
- Then file descriptor `1` is duplicated to file descriptor `10`
- Then file descriptor `3` (which is file `new`) is duplicated to file descriptor `1` (which is `10` now).

All of above things refer to `> new` in your command. Then the same sequences occurred, but for file descriptor `2`, refer to `2>new` in your command.

After that, you have two file descriptor `10` and `11` both point to file new, and these descriptor become `stderr` and `stdout` of `ls`. When `ls` running, it wrote to both `stderr` and `stdout`, which point to the same file `new` and part of output was truncated, because `stdout` had overwritten `stderr`.

Comment: Where's the _race condition_? 10 and 11 above are backups of the original stdout/stderr with close-on-exec. You'd only get those if you redirected a builin or compound command as otherwise there would be no need to _restore_ those fds since you run the command in a separate process anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `10` and `11` both pointed to `new` and when writing to `10` and `11` at the same time, is it not a race condition? How about the weird output?

Comment: No they don't, check your log above. dup2(1, 10) saves the original stdout as fd 10, then dup(3, 1) assignes "new" to stdout. They don't write at the same time, there's one write after the other, there's nothing non-deterministic here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: How about the weird output? I see the non-deterministic in write action. As the result, some output were missing. It's not deterministic like when you do `>new 2>&1`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, I try a `for` and see the output, it's really deterministic. Do you have any ideal about the weird output?

Comment: stdout overwrites stderr (each other, 1 and 2 have each their own pointer in the file), see my comment to the question.